# How to make two different elements have unique values in the same complex type in a XSD?

Tags: xml, validation, jakarta-ee, xsd

I want to validate that two fields have always unique values, inside the same complexType. I want to validate that in my XSD instead of doing it directly in code.

I know I can't use the type "xs:ID" two times inside the same complexType and unfortunately I can't make the  tag to work.

I already have one attribute "bookId" using the type "xs:ID" inside the complexType, so I thought in using the  tag to guarantee unique values to the other element "bookName".

I have the following structure:

```
<xs:complexType name="book">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "bookName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string"
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name = "bookPrice" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal"
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="bookId" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I already tried doing the following but with no success:

```
<xs:complexType name="book">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "bookName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:unique name="uniqueBookName">
                <xs:selector xpath="book"/>
                <xs:field xpath="bookName"/>
            </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name = "bookPrice" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal"
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="bookId" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'm using xml version 1.0. I don't know what I can try anymore from here in order to put it to work.

Someone have a hint on how to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers or comments are needed here.

1. Why do you believe you cannot assign the type xs:ID to two different elements in the same complex type?  In XSD 1.0, multiple ID attributes on the same element were forbidden, for compatibility with XML DTDs, but you're using elements, not attributes.  In XSD 1.1, multiple ID attributes are allowed, just as multiple ID children are allowed.

   Unless I'm missing something (always possible), you should probably distrust whatever source of information told you that xs:ID cannot be assigned to multiple elements within the same complex type.  It's possible of course that what they told you was something subtly different and you misunderstood some details.
2. If you wish to use uniqueness constraints instead of IDs, declare the uniqueness constraints on the element within whose scope the IDs must be unique, not on the book element or the bookName element.  Right now, your uniqueness constraints specify that the string value of the bookName element must be unique within that given bookName element.  Since you can never have more than one string value for the bookName element, this constraint will always be satisfied, with or without the xsd:unique.  If you want the book names to be unique with the ancestor element bookCollection (or whatever you call it), declare the uniqueness constraint there.

   Note that you can either require that book names be unique and separately that book IDs be unique, or that no two elements have either book names or book IDs that are the same as the book name or book ID of any other element.  In the first case, it's not an error for a book name to be the same as some book ID, only for it to be the same as the book name of some other book.
3. If you think that in the real world no two books have the same name, you may need to get out more.  ISBNs were invented precisely because it's not uncommon for different books to have the same title.

   If you think that book names are plausibly represented by the type xs:ID, you may need to send some time looking at books and also reading up on the xs:ID type, which requires its values to be identifiers beginning with a letter and containing no whitespace. Looking at the books currently on my desk, I cannot see a single one with a title that could be a valid xs:ID value.

   Prices are mostly given with numeric values, so xsd:string is probably a bit loose as a datatype, for someone who cares at all about validation.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. 1) You are right. I saw this from a trust-worthy source: "A complex type cannot include more than one attribute of type xsd:ID, or any type derived from xsd:ID." In my case, I have one attribute and one element. So I guess that is not a problem to use the xs:ID in both the element and the attribute. Nonetheless, I tried to put the type xs:ID in the element "bookName" and when I tested it didn't validate the uniqueness of the values. 2) You are suggesting that I pass the unique tag out of the "bookName" scope but still inside of the complexType "book"?

Comment: No, I am not suggesting that you apply the uniqueness constraint within the scope of a single book (which is what I take the type `book` to be trying to describe).  I suggest that you specify the uniqueness constraint to the element within whose scope the identifiers are required to be unique.  That might be an element representing a collection of books, or the element which occurs at the root of your document, or somewhere else.  But it's utterly pointless to say that the ID of a book must be unique within that book.

Comment: Ok, imagine that I have indeed a complexType that is a bookCollection. Inside that complexType, I have an element book. Imagine now that I have a lot of elements that have the type="bookCollection". My idea was to put the unique tag in the bookCollection directly, so I could apply the constraints to the books and all the elements that refered the type "bookCollection" would "benefit" from those constraints. The problem is, I can't do this. It only works if I declare the unique tag in the parent nodes (the elements that have the type bookCollection), and I end up with a lot of unique tags.

Comment: XSD uniqueness and identity constraints are given on elements, not on types. This positioning may be easier to remember if you think of it as analogous to referential integrity constraints in SQL, which are specified for columns, and are not part of the type of the column.